# I want a feature to temporarly block my website from accessing?

Tags: php, blocking

Hi from time to time , i want to shutdown my site for maintenance ...

How could i do this? I've seen a option in phpbb to block the site by admin and then unblock them..

Is there any apis for this or tell me a method of how to do this?

I'm using php for my website..

Comment: Disconnect the server (but then you can't access it yourself) B)

Comment: No .. that wont work.. When my customers enter my site they should be notified of site maintenance and they should not be allowed to login

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I generally use a `.htaccess` file that contains something like this :

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=MY_IP_ADDRESS
RewriteRule    ^$  /down.html  [L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=MY_IP_ADDRESS
RewriteRule    [^/down.html$]  /down.html  [L]
```

Nice things with this idea are :

- No PHP code involved -- which means I can totally do whatever I want with my PHP application, totally deleting it and re-uploading it, for instance, without any problem
- I can test the website from one IP address *(replacing `MY_IP_ADDRESS` by my real IP address)*, while everyone else will see the content of `down.html`

Once the maintenance operation is finished, I just comment those 4 lines, and voila, the website is re-opened ;-)

Comment: My ip address will be a dynamic ip.. so will that affect me at any point of time?

Comment: If your maintenance operation only last for a couple of minutes, your IP address probably won't change during that time, will it ? *(I'm sometimes using a dynamic IP, and never had that problem)*

Comment: My operation may go upto 4 or 5 hours , and in that time if my internet connection is reset or my dynamic ip is changed someway  , what could i do? Then can i access my site .. I'm asking in curiosity

Comment: If your IP address changes, you won't be able to access your website ;; but changing the IP adresse in the .htaccess file will allow you to re-access you site, with your new IP ;-)  *(And you probably won't change of address 10 times in 5 hours ^^ )*